# EF Core Group By with Deferred Execution and SQL side grouping

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, entity-framework-core, ef-core-2.1

Using EF Core 2.1 which does support Group By translation but not after I project the key value.

I have a query that needs to allow for a range of grouping types and a range of aggregate types.

Group By: Year, Year/Month, Year/Month/Day etc

Aggregate By: Avg, Sum, Min, Max etc.

I created two `switch` statements, one for the grouping and one for the aggregation. My issue is that I am not able to defer execution and perform the grouping within SQL. If not, the resulting data set is quite large.

Is any of this a reasonable approach or should I just use a raw query?

This is deferred and grouped as desired but the key type is unique to year/month and I am not able to provide a general solution for the aggregates in the second `switch` if I wanted to group by something different such as year/month/day.

```
var query1 = series
     .GroupBy(k => new { k.Created.Year, k.Created.Month, });

var result1 = query1
    .Select(i => new { i.Key, Value = i.Average(a => a.DataValue) });
```

As soon as you convert the key to a string, grouping occurs client-side:

```
var query2 = series
      .GroupBy(k => k.Created.Year.ToString());

var result2 = query2
    .Select(i => new { i.Key, Value = i.Average(a => a.DataValue) });
```

This too causes grouping to occur client side:

```
var query3 = series
     .GroupBy(k => new { k.Created.Year, k.Created.Month, })
     .Select(i => new
     {
         Key = $"{i.Key.Year}-{i.Key.Month}",
         Values = i.ToList()
     });
```

Any ideas how to accomplish my query? Ideally I need a common group key that groups server-side or a method of passing the aggregate based on a function in the query. Generating a `string` based key seems to ensure that the grouping occurs client side.

Comment: Since I don't think there is a general solution, wondering what "etc" could be here "Group By: Year, Year/Month, Year/Month/Day etc"

Comment: @IvanStoev the full list is year, year/month, year/month/day, year/month/day/hour, month, day of month, day of month, day of week.

Comment: Tricky. I think I can handle all these except day of week which doesn't translate to SQL even if you group only by it.

Comment: The whole thing is a bit of a proof of concept project. Exclude day of week if you need to. Honestly I think this likely screams for a raw sql approach which I can handle.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The only way I was able to get SQL translation in EF Core 2.1 (and 2.2) was to group by composite *anonymous* type conditionally including the desired data parts:

```
bool includeYear = ...;
bool includeMonth = ...;
bool includeDay = ...;
bool includeHour = ...;

var query1 = series
    .GroupBy(e => new
    {
        Year = includeYear ? e.CreatedDate.Year : 0,
        Month = includeMonth ? e.CreatedDate.Month : 0,
        Day = includeDay ? e.CreatedDate.Day : 0,
        Hour = includeHour ? e.CreatedDate.Hour : 0
    });
```

Weirdly enough, if I create a special class for group key with exactly the same properties as the anonymous type and change `new { ... }` to `new MyKeyType { ... }`, EF Core switches to client evaluation.

Shortly, `GroupBy` (and not only) SQL translation is still unstable. Looks like we have to wait for 3.0 to get eventually improvements in that area.

Comment: Pretty much what I found. Thanks for the efforts.

Comment: @andleer No current? The above works currently. Or you mean something else?

Comment: OK, this works but it is pretty clunky. EF clunky, not your solution. I fear something changing in the EF and this solution being broken... Fair enough? I am going to play around with coding some raw SQL and see what I can get there. Then deice on the best course of action. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Agreed. Just instead of going raw SQL query directly, I would try first creating, mapping and using a [database scalar function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/what-is-new/ef-core-2.0#database-scalar-function-mapping) to convert the datetime to string key.